# How to select rows from an indexed pandas DataFrame, using the second indexed column?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a trivial pandas DataFrame, with a two-level index and a single value column:

```
            value 
| k1 | k2 |       |  
+----+----+-------+
| a  | b  | c     |
| d  | e  | f     |
| g  | h  | i     |
```

I can select rows using k1, like that:

```
df.loc[['a','d'], :]
```

and get:

```
            value 
| k1 | k2 |       |  
+----+----+-------+
| a  | b  | c     |
| d  | e  | f     |
```

But, when trying the same with k2, like that:

```
df.loc[:, ['b','e']]
```

I get the KeyError: "None of [['b', 'e']] are in the [columns]"

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
df.loc[(slice(None), ['b', 'e']), :]
```

More detailed explanation:

When doing `df.loc[idx_row, idx_col]`, the indexer 'idx_row' (in your case the list `['a','d']`) indexes the rows (so your multi-index), while 'idx_col' (in your case `:`) indexes the columns (in this case: all columns).
So you want to specify both levels of the multi-index in the row-indexer ('idx_row'). When you want to select from the second level, you have to specify that you want to include all elements of the first level using a slice, so 'idx_row' becomes `(:, ['b', 'e'])`. The only problem is that you cannot use `:` inside a tuple, so you need to use the equivalent `slice(None)`.
Pandas provides a small workaround to not have to use the more verbose slice:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:, ['b', 'e']], :]
```

See the docs on this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers